# Read the size of the member of the pds

Tags: rexx

How to read the size of the member of  a pds file. A pds file has many members. If we browse a pds we can see the member names, their creation date, time user, size, etc.
So how to get these attributes separately in variables.

Answer (score 3):

As Bruce mentioned LMMFIND will have the ISPF statistics for a PDS member.  Make sure to use the STATS YES on the service.  Also,  you may need to check for extended stats (variable ZLEXT ).  A site may chose to use extended stats if the member size exceeds 64K.  Please refer to the ISPF services Guide.  Below is the link for LMMFIND in the 2.1 manual.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmmfind.htm%23lmmfind

Answer (score 2):

If running under TSO/ISPF (you can do this in batch as well), you can use the [LMMFIND](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmmfind.htm%23lmmfind) service with the **stats(yes)** option. You will have to do

- [lminit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lminit.htm%23lminit)
- [lmopen](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmopen.htm%23lmopen)

before you do the **LMFIND**. Also as  zarchasmpgmr you will need to do **LMCLOSE** and **LMFREE**

If you want to display a member list, have a look at [LMMDISP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmmdisp.htm%23lmmdisp)

Comment: Don't forget to LMCLOSE and LMFREE. :)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the statistics you write about are maintained by ISPF. There are many ways to create a member outside of ISPF, and those members will **not** have those statistics. The ISPF service LMMSTATS will set those stats (the 3.5 R panel is a front end to that service). The order of calls is

- [LMINIT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lminit.htm%23lminit)
- [LMMSTATS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmmstats.htm%23lmmstats)
- [LMFREE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmfree.htm%23lmfree)

For some reason, LMMSTATS doesn't require the LMOPEN and LMCLOSE services.

Comment: I believe that LMOPEN and LMCLOSE aren't required as they are effectively done for the PDS directory, which is where stats are held (in the user data section of a member's directory entry), by LMINIT and LMFREE respectively. That is, I think, LMINIT opens the directory and LMOPEN opens the actual PDS member. LMCLOSE closes the PDS member, LMFREE closes the PDS directory. So to get stats and member list you only need LMINIT/LMFREE.

Answer (score 0):

It's been ages, but if the PDS does not have ISPF stats (or the STATS are dubious (eg they can be changed outside of ISPF)). Then you could look to processing the directory.

However, by default a PDS directory doesn't contain that much info, so unless ISPF stats exist you couldn't get much info. What a PDS directory does have is a user-definable area and it's that area hat ISPF utilises. This area is preceeded by a length descriptor (see link for more info).

Another reason why ISPF stats may not exists or be accurate, is that, I think (if I recall correctly), that you can remove the stats, which can free some directory space (potentially get around E37 Abend or circumvent it happening).

I can't recall having tried with Rexx (did write an Assembler PDS unload utility), but you might be able to open and read the directory using **EXECIO** on the BASE name of the PDS (ie not including (member)).

The directory is blocked at 256 bytes.  More info in regards to the structure can be found here [PDS Directory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idad400/pdsd.htm). I don't believe that this would work properly for PDSE's though.

Comment: To me, this is the best answer as it is usually better to not rely on ISPF and the various LM* functions if you ever encounter non-ISPF datasets. For PDS and PDSE, allocate the base dataset (that is, just DSN with no member name), open it using RECFM U, BLKSIZE 256 and you can read the PDS directory - this can certainly be done with EXECIO. Sadly, if the dataset doesn't have reliable statistics (ISPF or otherwise...libraries of executables will also have some useful info for you), the only way to get the member length is to read the member from starting TTR until an EOF marker.

Comment: And KEYLEN=8, otherwise you'll get the first member (stored as the key in the CKD format) of the record duplicated in your I/O buffer, and you may buffer overflow if you allocated only 256 bytes.