# How te read the size of a pds member using lminit,lmmfind..?

Tags: rexx

I want to read size of members of a pds
For example:-

```
my pds name is - my.pds.cics
If i browse this pds I will find details like below:
     name     prompt size     created ..............
____PDS1             0051e   25/03/2016
____PDS2             006be   25/03/2016
____PDS3             0078e   25/03/2016
____PDS4             0051g   25/03/2016
```

I want to read the size of all the members of this pds and store it in variable.
`ex. var1 = 0051e`

Please help me how to o it.I tried using lmmfind. Can anyone help me with the codes in REXX.

Comment: You should have a look at a near duplicate question here [Read the size of the member of the pds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180974/read-the-size-of-the-member-of-the-pds)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the variables available in [LMMFIND](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54sg00/lmmfind.htm%23lmmfind)

if it is a load module, ZLSIZE should hold the size

if it is a FB file and ispf stats are set, ZLCNORCE will hold the number of records. and

```
 size = NumberOfRecord * RecordLength
```

if it is VB, you are stuffed.

The other option is to treat the file as a recfm=u and write a program and read the raw data. You should be able calculate the approximate size from the Member-start/end positions. There are IBM manuals that document the format.

Comment: Although not necessarily that efficient, you aren't stuffed if it's VB. You could do either VB or FB buy getting the directory list using either LMMLIST and then read through all records via EXECIO, which can handle VB (obtaining and accumulating the record lengths).